# How to make a box with a title on its border in HTML?

Tags: html, css

If there any way to make a box looks like the one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKftB.jpg) with HTML/CSS:

[image]

Comment: please add your current code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may be looking for the HTML `fieldset` and `legend` elements, which apply to forms.

From MDN:

> [***<fieldset>***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)
>
> The HTML `<fieldset>` element is used to group several controls as
>   well as labels (`<label>`) within a web form.
>
> [***<label>***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)
>
> The HTML Label Element (`<label>`) represents a caption for an item in
>   a user interface.

As mentioned before, the `fieldset` and `legend` elements are used when creating forms.

If you just want to put a label box on a border, you can use absolute positioning, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="label">I'm a Box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

#label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The above code renders this:

[image]

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pwp3ynsz/2/)

Comment: A big downvote from me. This answer is completely wrong semantically. Quoting MDN: "The HTML <fieldset> element is used to group several controls as well as labels (<label>) within a web form.".

Answer (score 4):

Use a `fieldset` tag and a `legend` in it.
Sample:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>I'm A Box</legend>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "position absolute", something like below:

```css
.a {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">test</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```